# electron's remote.getGlobal() returns "undefined" after window.location.replace()

Tags: javascript, undefined, electron, window.location

I've been fiddling around with electron's remote module.
In my main-process I've created this variable:

```
global.storage = {};
```

My renderer-process is initialised with a file called startup.html.

```
win.loadURL('file://' + __dirname + '/startup.html')
```

In there, I include a javascript file containing the following function:

```
function enterMain(value){
    remote.getGlobal('storage').exmpl = value;
    window.location.replace('./general.html');
}
```

The value I'm passing is "hello", and when calling upon...

```
console.log(remote.getGlobal('storage').exmpl);
```

...after assigning the value it returns "hello", as it should. However, once the window location has been replaced to general.html, in which I include a javascript file containing this function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     console.log(remote.getGlobal('storage').exmpl);
});
```

...it returns *undefined*.
Why? Can anyone help me make sense of this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are a few things in play here:

- The `remote` module caches remote objects in the renderer process on first access.
- Properties that are added to a remote object in the renderer process are not propagated back to the original object in the main process.
- Navigation restarts the renderer process.

With that in mind here's what's probably going on in your code:

1. `remote.getGlobal('storage')` creates a new remote object and caches it.
2. `remote.getGlobal('storage').exmpl = value` adds a new `exmpl` property to the remote object in the cache but doesn't propagate it to the original object in the main process.
3. `window.location.replace('./general.html')` restarts the renderer process which blows away the remote object cache.
4. `console.log(remote.getGlobal('storage').exmpl)` creates a new remote object since the cache is empty, but since the original object in the main process doesn't have an `exmpl` property it's also `undefined` on the new remote object.

The `remote` module seems deceptively simple at first, but it has many quirks, most of which are undocumented and as such may change in the future. I would suggest limiting the use of the `remote` module in production code.

Comment: I see, is there any way then to keep a variable stored between page-transitions, without relying on a server?

Comment: @Himmelslaub If you want to persist state between pages keep it in the main process (as you've been doing), but use the `ipcRenderer` and `ipcMain` modules to sync the state instead of the `remote` module.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that!

Comment: Thanks for providing such a clear answer, @VadimMacagon! For a simple example of how to use `ipcMain` and `ipcRenderer` to set a global variable value in the Main process, look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52167197/293280